# How do I set the font for a published Google Sheets chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Google Sheets supports the [publishing of interactive charts](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTwOwTM4ZZOWWymkeTflYg0wQhvy-FcP7ovN2Tq-wqHo6VEvdMRFLlRpqQeeWdavGAWUAPy7hIl0env/pubchart?oid=1027865583&format=interactive), but the resulting charts do not use the font set in the sheet.

How do I set the font for a published Google Sheets chart?

Comment: I suggest you to send a feature request directly to Google. This can be done from the Help menu from your spreadsheet. By the other hand, in order to have full control of how a chart is displayed instead of publishing a chart made in Google Sheets use the Google Charts API. For details see [how to use Google Charts with Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets). If you need further help, please add a brief descrition of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén So, the answer would be: There is currently no way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using different fonts?

Comment: @Rubén What do you mean? There's no option to change fonts in published charts and changing it in the chart itself results in the published chart in either Comic Sans or something that looks line Times, regardless of the chosen font.